# What is the last word being spoken in this audio clip/sentence?

Tags: spoken-language, listening

I'm translating an anime episode, and it's pretty much done, save this part and another line. I've tried asking a few people, I've been on reddit, I'vve listened to it one way too many times, but it's all been to no avail.
Here are the preceding lines:

「幸せすぎるんです、 きっと. 私の何倍も、 何十倍も.」(She's too happy, I'm sure of it. Tens of times, a hundred times happier than me.)

「今のあなたは?」(How happy are you right now?)

[LINE](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1C9Rf0MmLdV)

「ドレスも指輪もお嬢様の借り物です。ですから,(---) 」(This dress and the jewelry I'm wearing are both things Ojou-sama let me borrow, so ---)

What the heck is that word? It sounds like "tabun" at first, but it definitely doesn't work in context. The sounds are like, タ and フ, but that doesn't seem to work either.

(as an aside, forgive my writing, I had to cobble together the kana and kanji for the lines because my writing/reading skills are severely lacking.)

-

I feel like asking for another line is too much, but if you're willing to help, I'm also confused on another part as well. [This line](http://vocaroo.com/i/s0mPt8Oc1lTr), preceded by "I'm begging you, please, don't go!" and proceeded by "Please, for my sake, allow me just a little of your time. To be allowed just one night...is my dream.", is stumping me.

Answer (score 2):

１ 「[多分]{たぶん}」

２ 「[今宵]{こよい}[一夜]{ひとよ}、今宵ただ一夜、[私]{わたくし}のために時間を[割]{さ}いてください。」